# How to perform logistic regression with lasso using GLMSELECT?

Tags: logistic, sas, lasso

I am trying to perform logistic regression with lasso. For the logistic regression part I am using `PROC LOGISTIC` but I am not sure how to do lasso with `PROC LOGISTIC`. I searched online  and found that `PROC GLMSELECT` allows us to do lasso. But I am not sure how to do logistic regression with lasso using `PROC GLMSELECT`.

**Note:** I posted this question in the [SAS Discussion Forum](http://support.sas.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=13929&tstart=0).

Comment: I don't think you can: GLMSELECT only does linear models. If you are willing to use R or Matlab, there is the glmnet package.

Comment: @Simon Byrne +1 for R and glmnet.  Glmnnet can handle logistic regression with both the lasso and the elastic net. It's also an extremely fast implementation of the algorithm, and I suggest trying it out if you know any R.

Answer (score 7):

Code the outcome as -1 and 1, and run glmselect, and apply a cutoff of zero to the prediction. For a reference to this trick see 
Hastie Tibshirani Friedman-Elements of statistical learning 2nd ed -2009
page 661 
"Lasso regression can be applied to a two-class classifcation problem by
coding the outcome +-1, and applying a cutoff (usually 0) to the predictions."

It's a quick and dirty trick.

Lasso penalty can be applied to logistic regression, but it's not implemented in sas. In that case you have to try the R packages.